# Matlab: EulerSieve with Boolean vectors

Tags: matlab, primes

I implemented Euler's Sieve with integer arrays in MATLAB and everything worked well:

```
function [L] = EulerSieve1(N)
%This function allows to find all prime numbers until N using Euler's
%sieve algorithm
L=2:N;
P=2;
i=1;
while (P^2)<=N
    L1=L;
    if L(i)>=P && L(i)<=N/P
        L1(i)=L(i);
        i=i+1;
    end
    L2=P*L1;
    L=setdiff(L,L2);
    P=P+1;
end
end
```

Now, I want to implement the algorithm using Boolean vectors so that the output would be a Boolean vector with `N` elements with 1s in elements which indices are prime.

```
function [L] = EulerSieve2(N)
%This function allows to find all prime numbers until N using Euler's
%sieve algorithm and returns the array with 1s for all indices with prime
%values and 0s for others
L=logical(1:N);
P=2;
I=2;
K=2;
while (P^2)<=N
    L1=L;
    L2=L;
    if I>=P && I<=N/P
        L1(I)=0;
        I=I+1;
    end
    while K<N
        if L1(K)==0
            L2(K*P)=0;
            K=K+1;
        end
    end
    L=L2;
    P=P+1;
end
L(1)=0;
end
```

The function breaks at this point:

```
(17          if L1(K)==false)
```

What is wrong with the second code?

Answer (score 0):

For your second function, your code is stuck in the `while (K<N)` loop.
The value for `K` does not increment if `L1(K)` is `1`. *(What do you want to do when `L1(K)==1`?)*

---

Now, I'm not sure if you have the condition that you must work with binaries. If not, a much easier solution would be to use your first function and array indexing:

```
A = EulerSieve1(N); % Get primes from 1:N
B = false(1,N); % [1,N] matrix of logical false
B(A) = true; % Set elements in B, at indices specified by vector A, as true
```